# open and Edit a Word document Online in Client Browser

Tags: asp.net, ms-office

I want to open and Edit a Word Document Online means open the document in client browser Without save the document on user System

and when edit the document that would be saved on server.

Below are the steps:

1. Browse a file using fileupload or  Select a file.
2. Use the file upload file and when hit on a button,the file needs to opened/edited something like an GoogleDoc. Or Open in Editor) without save on Client/User machine.
3. User makes necessary changes and save the file on Server.

Note: i am also good to open the word file in editor.

I also tried the Interop but did not get any success like not ablt to maintain the formating of text ex: hyperlink

please reply ASAP and if possible send me the example.

I am really thankful to you.

Best Regards,

Comment: User1009771 what is exactly your question? You need a Word editor in Asp.Net which runs in the client browser?

Comment: You can't expect full scale example sent to you without a bounty. Also the question is not very detailed. Based on this question it seems you want someone else to do all the work. This isn't exactly how it works :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Google docs for such task.

All you can do - create a Sharepoint site, and edit it as you need.

Comment: I do not have knowledge about Sharepoint. Can't it possible in any editor like telerik

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't specified any constraints you can try an activex component (not that I would recommend this):
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286023
or
http://www.anydraw.com/

If Word isn't a hard requirement use a Richtexteditor. There are a lot of them and for free.

Comment: yea i used a telerik Rad Editor but didn't get any success because the word formatting is not maintain in Editor.

Comment: Word formatting will most likely not be maintained because it's not Word. Can you shed some light on your requirements, or the system you are building?